# Server Requirements for publishing android app

Tags: android, mysql, sdk

I am at the verge of completing my Android App.
- The App constantly depends on data from MySQL which I am planning to place on my server box (accessible via internet).
- There will be constant data flow from and to the App & DB.

What would be your recommendation on the Server (H/W). Do I need any special configuration to get seamless transfer of data? Any ideas/ suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Ram

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on the workload.
But basically, if you want to handle a **light workload** you can rely on **your box**. But later on **if the workload gets high, just put your application on the cloud**.
If you don't want to rewrite anything, you can certainly use an Infrastructure As A Service Cloud such as:

- Amazon AWS
- Rackspace
- Heroku
- Rackspace

To make your decision I would advice you to look at [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://conferences.sigcomm.org/imc/2010/papers/p1.pdf&ei=b_PJTq-JHer20gH-tMAu&usg=AFQjCNHCnQonOVf0DpkXzSB1nfaJujijcQ) at leas to get an idea of the criteria (even if it is rather old).

If you want to rewrite it to be really shaped for the Cloud, consider using:

- Google App Engine
- Amazon BeanStalk